# Smooth mesh or flat mesh

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hey I have  done retopo my Barrell of my Gun , its a game model, I'm confused weather I smooth it or leave it like that because smoothing is Getting worse and I cant increase geometry. I just want to know which kind or geometry go for a game model

Comment: Hello, what do you mean? What does it give when you smooth?

Comment: Hi, I've voted to close this as opinion based, because right now, it just sounds like an aesthetic question: "Does smooth or flat look better?"  But I think you should consider more carefully what you want to ask-- and perhaps ask a question like, "Why does this smooth shaded mesh look bad, and what can I do to improve it without increasing the vertex count?"

Answer (score 1):

if you mean the right click>shade smooth made you obj look bad,and the object data properties>normals>auto smooth wouldn't help,then maybe your normal were mess.

to fix the normal,you can go to edit mode,select all>mesh>normals>recalculate outside.

[image]